# Uninstalled Julia - How to reset conda path variables

Tags: python, anaconda, julia, conda

I uninstalled Julia, JuliaPro using windows Remove Program option from Control Panel. But it looks like it has manipulated my conda python distribution paths; now the conda-base environment points to juliapro.

1. How can I remove/uninstall everything related to Julia/Juliapro permanently
2. point my conda to its original base path that is used for python.

   ```
   (base) C:\>conda info

    active environment : base
   active env location : C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3
           shell level : 1
      user config file : C:\Users\username\.condarc
   populated config files : C:\Users\username\.condarc
         conda version : 4.6.7
   conda-build version : not installed
        python version : 3.6.5.final.0
      base environment : C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3  (writable)
          channel URLs : https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/win-64
                         https://conda.anaconda.org/intel/noarch
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/win-64
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/main/noarch
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/win-64
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/free/noarch
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/win-64
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/r/noarch
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/win-64
                         https://repo.anaconda.com/pkgs/msys2/noarch
         package cache : C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\pkgs
                         C:\Users\username\.conda\pkgs
                         C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\pkgs
      envs directories : C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\envs
                         C:\Users\username\.conda\envs
                         C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\envs
              platform : win-64
            user-agent : conda/4.6.7 requests/2.18.4 CPython/3.6.5 Windows/10 Windows/10.0.17134
         administrator : False
            netrc file : None
          offline mode : False
   ```

Comment: What does `where conda` says from your cmd prompt?

Comment: @FabienP

[C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\Library\bin\conda.bat, 

C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\Scripts\conda.exe,

C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\condabin\conda.bat]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Remove/uninstall Julia
2. Remove `.julia` folder - usually it is `%HOMEPATH%\.julia`
3. Have a look at `%HOMEPATH%\.conda` the `environments.txt` file there could point to your Julia - edit the file
4. Have a look at `jupyter_notebook_config.py` at `%HOMEPATH%\.jupyter` - likely your Julia conda is referenced there. You can safely delete that folder.
5. Open *System properties -> Advanced -> Environment variables*  and remove Julia related paths

Normally you should be clean after the steps above :-)

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there is a genuine `conda` install in `C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda`, as you can find the conda executable and scripts there according to your comment:

> ```
> C:\> where conda
> C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\Library\bin\conda.bat
> C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\Scripts\conda.exe
> C:\Users\username\.juliapro\JuliaPro_v1.0.3.1\conda\3\condabin\conda.bat
> ```

Likely deleting this directory will remove your Julia install, but you should ensure your initial conda install still exists somewhere else beforehand.

From the result of `conda info`, I expect you will find your previous install under `C:\Users\username\AppData\Local\conda\conda\`.